# Azure creates duplicate webjobs for Scheduled and Continuous

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a scheduled web job created in Azure app service developed using C#. I want to change my web job from scheduled to continuous, but upon deploying the web job from visual studio it created a new instance of the web job in the Azure portal(1-Continuous and 1-Scheduled).

Duplicate Web Jobs in Azure Portal

[image]

**webjob-publish-settings.json**

- Before:
  `{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "SampleWebJob",
  "runMode": "OnDemand"
  }`
- After:
  `{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "SampleWebJob",
  "runMode": "Continuous"
  }`

I would like to overwrite the existing web job instead of creating a new one. Is there any way I can do it?

Also is there any way I can achieve this using ARM templates?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the webjob is the same one, azure will overwrite it. And in your case actually it's the new webjob that's why it creates a new one.

If you only have one webjob and you want to change the type and don't want keep it after deployment, you could set `Delete Existing Files` to true.

[image]

If you have more than one webjob, you have to delete it on the portal or go to you web kudu site and delete it from the `app_data` folder.